# Diagnosing PCI issues

Tags: troubleshooting, computer-building, pci

I'm upgrading a PC for a friend, and have run into a problem with upgrading the motherboard.  I've been assembling custom PCs for the best part of a decade now, so I'm happy enough with the basics at the very least.

The motherboard, CPU and graphics card were all updated at once - after this was done, the machine POSTs but the PCI wireless card, as well as the PCI-E graphics card, do not seem to be recognised at all by the system.  No trace of them anywhere in the BIOS, or the POST output, or in Windows.  I booted into Linux and ran an `lspci` which also showed up no sign of them.

What is the best step to go about diagnosing this?  Is it likely/feasible that the motherboard's PCI bus is just defective and it needs to be RMAed?  Are there any other common gotchas that might cause these symptoms?

For reference, the components in question are:

- CPU: Celeron E1400
- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-G31M-ES2L
- Graphics card: TBC (a low end card from a couple of years ago; worked flawlessly before the mobo change)
- PCI WNIC: Edimax 7128G

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I assume you've swapped this between the two PCI ports?  Have you checked to ensure that PCI-E is enabled in the BIOS?  I haven't used Gigabyte boards with PCI-E, but they used to ship with AGP disabled when they had onboard video.

Comment: Jack, I read through the manual for that motherboard and the way the video out works (by default) is that the onboard video is only used if the PCI-E Card is not detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that either the motherboard is faulty or something was set incorrectly in the BIOS. Based on the motherboard manual you should try the following:

[image]

If that doesn't work, you probably have an RMA on your hands.